# Show several images in one div

Tags: html

How to show several images in one div using css and html?
Ex: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3066306/6f04718aa19dcc4b88192304a0f9a307 .

Here what I have done so far:

```html
<body>
  <div class="deck">
    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/kXlrGioGfFKOvibpsPzzGx16cP2.jpg" alt="testimage">
    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/zzfwhweu5reCv2Loqzon7Q5WAd5.jpg" alt="testimage">
    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/sGuZHYvu0mXeQCwvJ5yzk2Yoytq.jpg" alt="testimage">
    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/4Ar01t6sW1ZZBcbz2R1wqjzIBdr.jpg" alt="testimage">

  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wa9gfgvz/

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/wa9gfgvz/2/

Comment: ok, it's working well, what's your problem, i didn't see any

Comment: I want show the images like this example: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3066306/6f04718aa19dcc4b88192304a0f9a307

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you want, but adding a width isn't enough? ` .deck  { width: 444px }`

Comment: Hey @MappyLord, does my answer below helped you? If yes, can you please mark it as corret?

Answer (score 1):

Separate the images in two different divs and put that divs inside a main div, then if you want, you can center the ContainerDiv or do whatever with that, and the content will be always two images per row. 
But I suggest to use bootstrap to this kind of feature, but, anyways, here it come:

```
<div class='ContainerDiv'>
      <div class="deck">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/kXlrGioGfFKOvibpsPzzGx16cP2.jpg" alt="testimage">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/zzfwhweu5reCv2Loqzon7Q5WAd5.jpg" alt="testimage">
      </div>

      <div class="deck">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/sGuZHYvu0mXeQCwvJ5yzk2Yoytq.jpg" alt="testimage">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w220_and_h330_bestv2/4Ar01t6sW1ZZBcbz2R1wqjzIBdr.jpg" alt="testimage">
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.deck{
   display:flex;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prtanruz/

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
  .deck{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    }

  .deck img{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
```

Refer: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/wa9gfgvz/3/)